# How to release one single jar for android?

Tags: android, android-studio, jar, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to use the gradle to release Jar for android project. The jar may contain other 3rd jars. I can use the following script to release jar by my source code without 3rd jars:

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    def name = variant.buildType.name
    if (name.equals(com.android.builder.core.BuilderConstants.DEBUG)) {
        return; // Skip debug builds.

    }
    def task = project.tasks.create "jar${name.capitalize()}", Jar
    task.dependsOn variant.javaCompile
    task.from variant.javaCompile.destinationDir
    artifacts.add('archives', task);
}
```

Then I found a [open source code](https://github.com/rholder/gradle-one-jar) and it seems can do the release task. Unfortunately, when I add it into my project, the following compile error occurred.

> The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins.

PS: I also need merge shared library into the jar if possible.